# Azure Java SDK - Can't fetch resource metrics: ApiVersion: 2018-01-01 does not support query at non Arm resource Id level

Tags: java, azure

I am using Azure's Java SDK and trying to fetch a resource's metrics to then fetch information about it's costs.

```xml
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.microsoft.azure</groupId>
    <artifactId>azure</artifactId>
    <version>1.31.1</version>
</dependency>
```

I am trying to fetch a resources metrics:

```java
 azure.metricDefinitions().listByResource(resourceGroup.id());
```

But I get:

> Status code 400, {"code":"BadRequest","message":"ApiVersion: 2018-01-01 does not support query at non Arm resource Id level"}

I am not sure how to fix this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

listByResource is expecting the resourceId of a resource (ie. a storage account or VM).  But you are passing the resourceId of a resource group.